# Transaction - Unexpected rollback happening - not able to understand

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I am doing a simple operation of:

1. First delete all the records. If exception rollback.
2. If no exception, insert all the records. If exception, nothing is deleted, rollback to before 1.
   For this, I have one API endpoint which is calling the function example.
   In the example function, I have the logic.
   In Repo, I am using two queries.
   Also, exception is getting printed.

I have tried various combinations of Propagation but I am not able to figure why Unexpected Rollback is happening. Please help.

API Endpoint:

```
functionAPI(){
    exampleFunction(...);
}
```

```
@Transactional
exampleFunction(...){
  try {
    repo.deleteall(...);
    repo.insertall(...);
  } catch {
    System.out.println("exception");
  }
}
```

Repo:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(...)
deleteall(...)

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(...)
insertall(...)
```

Comment: There is an exception, which you catch, and thus messes up the transaction. Don't catch the exception. Also if the `exampleFunction` is in the same class as the `functionAPI` method the `@Transactional` on that method doesn't do anything. Finally your methods need to be `public` for `@Transactional` to work.

Comment: Hello. 
Yes all the methods are public. 
exampleFunction is in different class than functionAPI.
As for the catch part, I want to catch in exampleFunction and setReason as to why the rollback is happening, that is why I am catching.

Comment: Don't catch as that messes up the transaction support in Spring or at least re-trhow the exception so that Spring sees the exception. Else it will try to commit, concludes that something is wrong and rollback and throws the `UnexpectedRollbackException` as it expected everything to be ok (due to your catching of the exception).

Comment: Hello. I tried what you said. I threw the exception and I caught that in functionAPI. But my question, if I use rollbackFor, is that correct approach?

Comment: There is nothing in your question about rollback for.

Comment: I do want that no try catch block being implemented in functionAPI function. 
Because after throwing the exception, I will need to handle that in the funcitonAPI.
If there is any other way of letting spring can know that rollback happens, please guide.

Comment: Why would you need to handle that? It is a runtime exception. The exception is to handle the exceptional case and thus the rollback. So apart form manually doing transaction management there is no other way.

Comment: Yes, I understant that RuntimeExceptions should not be handled. But,
For eg, If I have an SqlException for DataIntegrityViolation, for this exception, If I want to send the user some message, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Just catch a `DataAccessException` that is all there will be to catch in the end. In your function, so either way you always need to handle the exception (if you want that) but **outside** the transactional boundary.

Comment: Outside the transactional boundary meaning in functionAPI, right? Catch the exception in functionAPI.

Comment: yes, else it will mess up the transaction support